# Table header repeated ssrs for every group instance

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have a tablix with a header and a data row. The grouping is for data row only. No page breaks applied for group instances. 
The problem I'm facing is that the header row is getting repeated for every group instance. every group instance is getting printed in a different table.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Edit the question to include the Row Group properties

Comment: It looks like your table is being repeated. Is your table inside of another table or list that is repeating for each property? You might just remove the outer table - though it's not clear what its purpose is.

Comment: @HannoverFist There is no outer table. This is the only table